# How to write single time switch case by passing parameter in JavaScript instead of repeating switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I submit form, getting the form values like question 1 and question 2 etc. This value of I am putting same condition. Based on condition I need to display values that is done but here is the problem I am passing question value to function that function contain switch. Switch is repeating more times due to I passing more parameter to the function.

Instead of writing more times, how can write switch to pass more parameter in my code.

Please help me anyone.

This is what I've tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var A = 10,
      N = 6,
      D = 3,
      NA = 0;
  var v1, v2, v3;
  
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    debugger;
    var q1v = $('input[name=q1]:checked').val();
    var q2v = $('input[name=q2]:checked').val();
    var q3v = $('input[name=q3]:checked').val();

    toString1(q1v, q2v, q3v);

    if ((q1v == "A" || q1v == "N") && ((q1 + q2 + q3) / 3 > 0.60)) {
      console.log("q1 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60%");
    } else if ((q2v == "A" || q2v == "N") && ((q1 + q2 + q3 / 3) > 0.60)) {
      console.log("q2 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60% ");
    } else if ((q3v == "A" || q3v == "N") && ((q1 + q1 + q1 / 3) > 0.60)) {
      console.log("q3 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60% ");
    } else {
      console.log("q1,q2 and q3 DisAgree or NotApplicable and also value is bellow 60% ");
    }
  });

  function toString1(v1, v2, v3) {
    debugger;
    switch (v1) {
      case "A":
        q1 = A;
        break;
      case "N":
        q1 = N;
        break;
      case "D":
        q1 = D;
        break;
      case "NA":
        q1 = NA;
    }

    switch (v2) {
      case "A":
        q2 = A;
        break;
      case "N":
        q2 = N;
        break;
      case "D":
        q2 = D;
        break;
      case "NA":
        q2 = NA;
    }

    switch (v3) {
      case "A":
        q3 = A;
        break;
      case "N":
        q3 = N;
        break;
      case "D":
        q3 = D;
        break;
      case "NA":
        q3 = NA;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <p>question 1</p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A">
    <label>Agree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="N">
    <label>Neutral</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="D">
    <label>Disagree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="NA">
    <label>Not Applicable</label>
  </p>
  <p>question 2</p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="A">
    <label>Agree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="N">
    <label>Neutral</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="D">
    <label>Disagree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="NA">
    <label>Not Applicable</label>
  </p>
  <p>question 3</p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="A">
    <label>Agree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="N">
    <label>Neutral</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="D">
    <label>Disagree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="NA">
    <label>Not Applicable</label>
  </p>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: use the `<>` instead in the post editor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object for the values, like

```
var values = {
    A: 10,
    N: 6,
    D: 3,
    NA: 0
};
```

and use it in `toString1`

```
q1 = values[v1];
q2 = values[v2];
// etc.
```

Comment: you could exchange one switch with one assignment of the call of the object's property.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object out of the question and use that to test your conditions. It's a bit neater and more reusable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    
    var q1v = $('input[name=q1]:checked').val()
    var q2v = $('input[name=q2]:checked').val()
    var q3v = $('input[name=q3]:checked').val()

    var answers = scores(q1v, q2v, q3v)

    // Test your conditions here with your new answers object
    // OR better yet, you can create a method for that
    
});

  function scores(a,b,c) {

      // this is the object that we will return
      var questions = {
        q1: {
          input: a,
          value: 0,
        },
        q2: {
          input: b,
          value: 0
        },
        q3: {
          input: c,
          value: 0
        },
        total: 0,
        base: 3        
      }

    for (var answer in questions){
      switch (questions[answer].input){
        case "A":
          questions[answer].value = 10
          questions.total += 10
          break;
        case "N":
          questions[answer].value = 6
          questions.total += 6
          break;
        case "D":
          questions[answer].value = 3
          questions.total += 3
          break;
        case "NA":
          questions[answer].value = 0
      }
    }
    return questions  
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend for="q1">Question 1</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A">
    <label>Agree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="N">
    <label>Neutral</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="D">
    <label>Disagree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="NA">
    <label>Not Applicable</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend for="q1">Question 2</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="A">
    <label>Agree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="N">
    <label>Neutral</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="D">
    <label>Disagree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="NA">
    <label>Not Applicable</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend for="q1">Question 3</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="A">
    <label>Agree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="N">
    <label>Neutral</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="D">
    <label>Disagree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="NA">
    <label>Not Applicable</label>
  </fieldset>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Didn't know about `<legend>`, nice! *question* in *switch* should be *questions* though

Comment: Right you are sir. Fixed that.